# CRUD application for employee tracking

Tags: java, spring

I don't know how to implement this, so I hope someone can help me.

I want to create a CRUD App with a login form, so for the login form, in the database, I have three rows: username, password and role. I will use it to verify the user when he inserts login info, of course, all of that is automatically implemented with Spring security.

However, I have automatic Spring security for login, and that works fine, what is my problem:

Should I have two tables for employees?
One with username, password and role and one table for first name, last name, salary and etc.?

Comment: Why are you considering using two tables for employees?

Comment: Your question is broad and mostly opinion-based, but I will note that it absolutely does make sense to separate out "user authentication" from "employment record".

Answer (score 1):

> Should I have two tables for employees? One with username, password, and the role and one table for first name, last name, salary, etc.?

Yes. It seems to be a valid approach to have separate tables because security and employee management sound like different concerns.

Having two tables (user, employee) will allow you to add different types of users in the future to the application. It's not said that a user will always be an employee. This will also allow you to use employee CRUD functionality outside of the Secured context of the application.

I have seen this pattern in most of the applications I was co-developing so far.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need three tables:

Keeping the users separate from employees allows for users that aren’t employees, such as a system user that background tasks run as.

It’s reasonable for users to have more than one role, so you’ll need a table associating a user to one or more roles.

Make sure password is stored as a 1-way hash, not as clear text.